# TypeError: value is undefined jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to extract object from json. But I get `TypeError: recent_prod[a] is undefined`. I had already did this many times with no error. But this time I cannot get where I am going wrong. Thank you.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var recents = "";
    var imges = "";
    var imge = "";
    var recent_prod = <?php echo $recent_prod; ?>;
    for(var a = 0; a < 8; a++)
    {
        imges = recent_prod[a].image;           //typeError.
        alert(imges);
        imge = imges.split[","];
        recents += '<a href="' + base_url + 'init/product/' + recent_prod[a].id + '">'+
                '<div class="related_prod_thumb">' +
                    '<div class="related_prod_img">'+
                        '<span class="helper"></span>'+
                        '<img src="' + base_url + 'uploads/thumbnail/' + imge + '" width="100">'+
                    '</div><div class="related_prod_title">' + recent_prod[a].title +'</div>'+
                    '<div class="related_prod_price">' + 'Rs. ' + recent_prod[a].price + '</div></div></a>';
    }
    $("#recent_views").html(recents);
});
```

Comment: Did you inspect the code as sent to the browser by viewing the browser page source? It sounds like the PHP-supplied value in `$recent_prod` is not as expected. It is usually a good idea to `json_encode()` a value from PHP that you are sending to JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the source code of the page and see if this line:

```
var recent_prod = <?php echo $recent_prod; ?>;
```

is actually printing `$recent_prod` properly, and if so, see if it is an array. Also, this line:

```
for(var a = 0; a < 8; a++)
{
    imges = recent_prod[a].image;
```

Is trying to read `recent_prod` without checking if it has content. Replace `8` with `recent_prod.length`. That is if `recent_prod` is also an array.

Comment: `recent_prod.length`. Doing this worked for me. Its silly mistake that JSON had only 6 length But I was looping upto 8. So I got error. Thank You. I wanted to actually fetch only part of JSON.

Answer (score 0):

To ensure only legit values are used, change

```
for(var a = 0; a < 8; a++)
```

to

```
for(var a in recent_prod)
```